# How to rewrite 'she sings like a bird'

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality, clauses

> **She sings like a bird**.

If I want to rewrite this sentence using '**as**' what would be the appropriate sentence?

1.*She sings as a bird does.*

2.*She sings, as a bird does.*

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite it?  What's wrong with "She sings like a bird"?  It's the most natural and common way of expressing the comparison.  If you do need an 'as... as' expression, I'd recommend the version without the comma, as the comma leaves your sentence as at least in principle interpretable as something like the rather unusual combination, "She sings, and a bird does too." (though the word order would more likely be "She sings, as does a bird").

Comment: It doesn't literally mean that she sings _in the same way_ that a bird does, which people obviously don't. If you want to use _as_, you would be better to include an adverb - "She sings as naturally/tunefully as a bird does."

Comment: @Jaime ok I got it. 

Comment: @KateBunting ok 

Comment: @Jaime I got your point. You said that if I do want to rewrite the sentence, I should drop the comma. That means **She sings like a bird=She sings as a bird does**. Now if I take a sentence "*I work in a hotel like my wife*" it means we both work. Therefore **I work in a hotel like my wife=I work in a hotel, as does my wife**. For this example I should keep the comma. Am I correct?